404 on Designer \ data-sources \ ProcessMaker 4
I have sucessfully installed ProcessMaker 4.10.1 with locally build Docker-Image.
But when i try to open some Designer sites like decision-tables, data-sources, projects i will get an 404 Error ("Oops! The page you are looking for could not be found"). But Designer - processes, screens and scripts  working fine.
I have tried to figure out the problem with checking ngix logs, but didn´t found an approach.
With older Versions 4.9.x and 4.8.x i have the same result. So i think there must be an problem with some dependencys, but i didn´t saw an corresponding error during the installation process.
Can somebody help?
